# How to use custom font with weasyprint

Tags: python, django, weasyprint

I have a django app and I would like to create a pdf from my django view.
I use weasyprint, and for some reason it doesn't accept my custom font.
The font url is working and when I render the same html with the same font-face, I see the correct font, but my pdf is rendered with a wrong one. I also tried the base64 font string, but no luck. My render code is:

```
import os
from weasyprint import HTML, CSS
from weasyprint.fonts import FontConfiguration

from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.urls import reverse


def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    font_config = FontConfiguration()
    font_string = '''
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'Titillium Web';
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: 300;
          src: local('Titillium Web Light'), local('TitilliumWeb-Light'), url('http://X.X.X.X:8000/static/fonts/titillium_web.woff2') format('woff2');
        }
        *, div {font-family: 'Titillium Web';}
    '''

    template = get_template(template_src)
    rendered_html  = template.render(context_dict)
    pdf_file = HTML(string=rendered_html).write_pdf(stylesheets=[
        CSS(settings.BASE_DIR +  '/gui/executive_summary.css'),
        CSS(string=font_string)],font_config=font_config)
    response = HttpResponse(pdf_file, content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename="report.pdf"'
    return response
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: for `weasyprint>=53` use `from weasyprint.text.fonts import FontConfiguration`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can read in documentation:

> WeasyPrint should support any font format handled by FreeType (any
>   format widely used **except WOFF2**)

SRC: http://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features.html#fonts

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18240619)

Comment: i agree with @yivi a direct link is not really answering the question, and only the part that solve the problem should be included as an answer, not to mention that weasyprint documentation are not really providing exact solution for font problems

Comment: The source website seems to have changed and it no longer includes the exception regarding WOFF2. Nevertheless, WOFF2 still doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know whether it's supported now?

Comment: `woff2_compress` is a tool that converts WOFF2 fonts into TrueType (`.ttf`) fonts. See https://github.com/google/woff2.  You can then utilize a `src: url(file://path/to/truetype/yourfont.ttf)` line in your CSS.

Comment: Woff2 is supported in weasyprint since [version 53](https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/releases/tag/v53.0), see [release blog](https://www.courtbouillon.org/blog/00009-weasyprint-53-what-s-new/).

Answer (score 9):

There are two ways.

1. Upload the font to a web server and add the link in the URL, e.g.:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Gentium;
    src: url(http://example.com/fonts/Gentium.otf);
}
```

2. If you want to use a font from a local directory, e.g.:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Gothan Narrow;
    src: url(file:///home/javed/Downloads/fonts/GothamNarrow-Light.otf)
}
```

Comment: Adding absolute path @font-face {
        font-family: kalpurush;
        src: url(file:///mnt/d/djangoprojects/dj-boot-modal/librarydb/static/librarydb/fonts/kalpurush.ttf);
    } solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you have `@font-face` rules in your CSS, you have to create a
`FontConfiguration` object:

```
fromweasyprintimport HTML, CSS
from weasyprint.fonts import FontConfiguration

font_config = FontConfiguration()
html = HTML(string='<h1>The title</h1>')
css = CSS(string='''
    @font-face {
        font-family: Gentium;
        src: url(http://example.com/fonts/Gentium.otf);
    }
    h1 { font-family: Gentium }''', font_config=font_config)
html.write_pdf(
    '/tmp/example.pdf', stylesheets=[stylesheet],
    font_config=font_config)
```

https://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html?highlight=FontConfiguration

Comment: ```from weasyprint.text.fonts import FontConfiguration```

Answer (score 2):

**Working !!!**

```
fromweasyprintimport HTML, CSS
from weasyprint.fonts import FontConfiguration

font_config = FontConfiguration()
html = HTML(string='<h1>The title</h1> html content here')

css = CSS(string='''            
      @font-face {
          font-family: 'TiroDevanagariMarathi';                
          src: url(../../static/fonts/TiroDevanagariMarathi-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
          }
      h1 { font-family: TiroDevanagariMarathi }''', font_config=font_config)
    

html.write_pdf(
    '/my_file_path/example.pdf', stylesheets=[css],
    font_config=font_config)
```

Comment: This helped me, I was forgetting to pass the `font_config` parameter to the CSS class

Comment: have you tried to use this with Google Fonts?  Thanks.

Comment: I'll try this with Google fonts

Comment: I've tried with Google Fonts without success. Sadly it seems to work only with static files.
Thanks for the answer tho, I've been struggling trying to get fonts working for the past hours!

Edit: the only thing I changed from the above example is the absolute path to the static file, such as `url(file:///home/user/project/font.ttf)`